# ARKit - Can you change planeDetection while in session?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have a popoverviewcontroller to toggle horizontal or vertical plane detection. I know that it is passed correctly using protocol and delegate, but it doesn't change the configuration for some reason. I change the configuration in the protocol function.

Thanks!

Comment: Post some code. What did try you? You are not providing enough information for us to help you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the configuration of a running session by calling `run(_:options:)` again with a new configuration.

If you leave the `options` parameter empty (or omit it), and pass a configuration of the same type that the session is currently running, everything about your session (existing anchors etc) stays the same, with the exception of whatever changes you made to the configuration.

```
// before
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
session.run(configuration)

// after
let newConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
newConfiguration.planeDetection = .vertical
session.run(newConfiguration)
```

In a case like this, if you change the plane detection settings but don't remove existing anchors when re-running the session, existing horizontal plane anchors will stay in the session, but won't get updated anymore.

---

It sounds like the problem you're seeing is that you're changing properties of a configuration you've already passed to the session, and not passing it to the session again — it's the act of calling `run` with your configuration that makes changes take effect.

Think of it like this: an `ARConfiguration` is like the order form you might use at a sandwich shop. You check the boxes saying you want onions and mayo, then give the form to the cashier. The form is on carbon paper, so they tear the copy off the back and give it to the kitchen, then hand the original back to you so you can show it at the pickup counter to claim your food. If you scribble out "mayo" and check guacamole instead, it's not going to change what the kitchen is making unless you go talk to the cashier again.